# How is it possible for IE 11 to behave this way?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

We have just re-coded our website to be responsive using Bootstrap 3.3.5 ... but when we test in Internet Explorer 10 or 11, the site behaves strange occasionally.
DOM elements are missing or is displayed in the wrong location.
Today when I was trying to debug, I noticed an image not loading. When I opened the IE DOM-Explorer, I found that IE had placed an `</div>` element inside an img-tag ... `<img class="nyhed-ikon" alt="Galleri" src="http://www.maskinbladet.</div>dk/assets/templates/..."></img>`
How is that possible?
I have also noticed unordered lists with `<li>` elements removed from their original position and placed inside a parent child `<div>` element.
How is it possible for IE to re-organize elements in the DOM to this extent?

Please help me .... I think I'm going mad.

Comment: Are you sure the html you feed it is without errors? You might use the W3C Validator to check that. IE sometimes make a guess to add a missing tag.

Comment: W3C Validator showing no errors or warnings in HTML code.

Comment: if you use fiddler is that div already there?

Comment: The `</div>` is not present in the raw HTML ... "view source" shows the HTML code normally ... only when viewed in IE is the tag present ... but it does not show every time the page loads ... press F5 and the page looks normal again ... clicking a few links on different sub-pages, and BANG it is back ... and not the same thing every time ... nearly impossible to debug.

Comment: Can't explain this strange behaviour in IE ... [DOM-Explorer vs Source](http://s22.postimg.org/5tjn6kshd/ie_dom_fail.jpg) ... 
Page validates in W3C Validator ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

It forces the browser the render at whatever the most recent version's standards are.

Comment: This was recommended by Bootstrap documentation ... would it be better to force IE 10 or IE 11 render condition?

Comment: I would use the last version. You can if you like force IE 10 or IE 11 render condition as following: If you separate with semi-colon, it sets compatibility levels for different versions. For example:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=9" />

Comment: I moved the X-UA-Compatible from HTML til .htaccess ... no change.

Comment: Check the Compatibility View of your IE

Comment: Browser Mode: IE10, Document Mode: Standards

Comment: What the result when you select as Browser Mode "Edge(Standards)".

Comment: Please Check im whiche mode is your web site displayed through this code. <script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Modus:" + document.compatMode);
</script>